# Limit/Block MQTT publish limit from thing in AWS IoT

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, iot, publish, rate-limiting

In AWS IoT Core, we created few things and allow policy for thing to publish certain topic.

Question here is that possible to limit the thing publish such as only 1000 publish per day on each things. This is not the AWS publish limit per second but our customized limit on things.

Any possibility to do in AWS IoT security policy on thing certificate? Or topic? This should be first level of limit to reject over-publish before it goes to rule engine.

Answer (score 3):

AWS offers a service called IoT Device Defender that allows you to collect metrics for individual clients, see: https://aws.amazon.com/iot-device-defender/

You can define a threshold for the number of published messages in a given time interval and configure automatic alerts if the threshold is exceeded. These alerts can be published to an SNS topic, so you can trigger further automatic actions like disabling the client's certificate to block further messages.

The relevant metrics can be found in the "Detect" section of AWS IoT Device Defender:

- Create security profile
- Cloud-side metrics
- Messages sent, messages received, message size...

Note that collecting these metrics is not free.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to limit per client.
As you know, 
Using certificate is only way to limit per client.
ex) change A client's certificate to inactive when it publish 1000 times a day.
You have to check publishing times per client, and then change certificate's state active/inactive.

Comment: Hi, you mean we need to do logging (i.e. store in database) for every publish that client send. So that, we can do checking on client publish rate? Else, I didn't find any IoT core service can do request check for publish limit even cloudtrail service.

Comment: I also couldn't find metric for IoT publishing limit per client. AWS IoT just support metric for publishing limit per account. ref . https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/metrics_dimensions.html . I don't know what best solution is to check publishing times per client.

Comment: I see. Thanks lot.